How to test custom hook with useEffect in React 18?
Hook:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useIsClient = () => {
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true);
  }, []);

  return isClient;
};

export default useIsClient;

Tests:
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";

import useIsClient from "./useIsClient";

describe("useIsClient", () => {
  it("returns false initially", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useIsClient());
    expect(result.current).toBe(false);
  });

  it("returns true after useEffect runs", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useIsClient());
    expect(result.current).toBe(true);
  });
});

Result:
 ❯ src/hooks/useIsClient.spec.ts (2)
   ❯ useIsClient (2)
     × returns false initially
     ✓ returns true after useEffect runs

Why does it fail to return false when I don't call any waitFor functions? Is this intended? How could I properly test this hook?

https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#result It's by the docs, I think it will call useEffect sync when in test mode. ;)

For testing hooks, you might rather take a look at https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library
